# Notation for Matrix Representation of linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Are these notations similar.

### $M_{B'}^{B}$ AND $M_{B}^{B'}$ OR $T_{B'}^{B}$ AND $T_{B}^{B'}$

Where M is change of basis from B to B'.
In my university book there is no clear indication of the same. Also, I have seen people on YouTube are referring this as linear transformation with respect to bases B and B'.

So does it not matter if we write B as subscript and B' as superscript or vice-versa.
Here is the link to book: https://egyankosh.ac.in/bitstream/123456789/87789/1/Unit-9.pdf

Comment: I don't think that any of these is a standard notation so whatever is the definition in your book you should use that. If it makes your work easier than redefine it...

Answer (score 3):

My preferred notation for this is that if $T: U \to V$ is a linear transformation with bases $B \subseteq U$ and $C \subseteq V$, then ${_C[T]_B}$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases. The reason for this is that you put in something in the basis $B$ on the right side of ${_C[T]_B}$, and you get something in $C$ on the left side. You also get nice rules, for example if we also have $S: V \to W$ and $D \subseteq W$ is another basis, the following equation holds over matrices:
$$   {_D[S]_C} \, {_C[T]_B} = {_D[S \circ T]_B},$$
where on the LHS we are using matrix multiplication, wheras on the RHS $S \circ T $ is the composition of linear operators. The double $C$ in the middle “cancels”.

From this equation though, you can figure out that if $T: V \to V$ is an operator and $B, C \subseteq V$ are both bases, then the matrices ${_B[T]_C}$ and ${_C[T]_B}$ are *not* the same. In particular, if $\operatorname{id}_V: V \to V$ is the identity operator, then ${_C[\operatorname{id}_V]_B}$ is the change-of-basis matrix from $B$ into $C$, while ${_B[\operatorname{id}_V]_C}$ changes from $C$ into $B$, and by the equation above we have
$$ {_B[\operatorname{id}_V]_C} \, {_C[\operatorname{id}_V]_B} = {_B [\operatorname{id}_V]_B} = I,$$
and hence those change-of-basis matrices are inverses of each other.

Comment: Wow, that's really intuitive notation, never seen it before

Comment: @joppy Thank you so much, this really helped me to understand how this works.